# “dass alle unsere Bewusstheit sich auf Irrthümer bezieht” – meaning of “sich beziehen”

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

Does anyone have any insights into what Nietzsche means by *sich beziehen auf* in this passage? Usually it means *to refer to* or *to apply to* or something similar, but I am not sure here. Those words do not seem to fit.

> Das Bewusstsein.— Die Bewusstheit ist die letzte und späteste Entwickelung des Organischen und folglich auch das Unfertigste und Unkräftigste daran. Aus der Bewusstheit stammen unzählige Fehlgriffe, welche machen, dass ein Thier, ein Mensch zu Grunde geht, früher als es nöthig wäre, "über das Geschick," wie Homer sagt. Wäre nicht der erhaltende Verband der Instincte so überaus viel mächtiger, diente er nicht im Ganzen als Regulator: an ihrem verkehrten Urtheilen und Phantasiren mit offenen Augen, an ihrer Ungründlichkeit und Leichtgläubigkeit, kurz eben an ihrer Bewusstheit müsste die Menschheit zu Grunde gehen: oder vielmehr, ohne jenes gäbe es diese längst nicht mehr!
>
> Bevor eine Function ausgebildet und reif ist, ist sie eine Gefahr des Organismus: gut, wenn sie so lange tüchtig tyrannisirt wird! So wird die Bewusstheit tüchtig tyrannisirt—und nicht am wenigsten von dem Stolze darauf! Man denkt, hier sei der Kern des Menschen; sein Bleibendes, Ewiges, Letztes, Ursprünglichstes! Man hält die Bewusstheit für eine feste gegebene Grösse! Leugnet ihr Wachsthum, ihre Intermittenzen! Nimmt sie als Einheit des Organismus!—Diese lächerliche Ueberschätzung und Verkennung des Bewusstseins hat die grosse Nützlichkeit zur Folge, dass damit eine allzuschnelle Ausbildung desselben verhindert worden ist. Weil die Menschen die Bewusstheit schon zu haben glaubten, haben sie sich wenig Mühe darum gegeben, sie zu erwerben—und auch jetzt noch steht es nicht anders! Es ist immer noch eine ganz neue und eben erst dem menschlichen Auge aufdämmernde, kaum noch deutlich erkennbare Aufgabe, das Wissen sich einzuverleiben und instinctiv zu machen,—eine Aufgabe, welche nur von Denen gesehen wird, die begriffen haben, dass bisher nur unsere Irrthümer uns einverleibt waren und **dass alle unsere Bewusstheit sich auf Irrthümer bezieht**!

My rough draft translation:

> Consciousness — Consciousness is the latest development of the organic, and is thus still unfinished and quite feeble compared to preceding developments. Consciousness leads to innumerable errors, which, ‘tempting fate’, as Homer says, cause an animal or a man to perish earlier than might otherwise be necessary. If the protective bond of the instincts were not very much more powerful, and if it did not generally serve as a regulator, mankind would necessarily have perished with open eyes from bad judgements and fantasies, from superficiality and credulity, in short, just from consciousness; or rather, without the instincts, mankind would have vanished long before!
>
> Before a function is fully formed and mature, it is a danger to the organism, and it is all the better if it is suppressed until then! Consciousness is thus thoroughly suppressed — and not least by our pride in it! It is believed that herein lies the essence of man; that which is enduring, eternal, ultimate, and most original in him! Consciousness is regarded as being a fixed, given state, with no possibility of growth or transitional stages! It is accepted as the ‘unity of the organism’! This ludicrous overestimation and misconception of consciousness has happily prevented it from maturing too rapidly. Because men believed that they already possessed consciousness, they scarcely bothered trying to acquire it, and this remains true today! The need to assimilate knowledge and make it instinctive is just now beginning to be recognized, and as of yet is not fully discernible — it is a need which is seen only by those who have grasped the fact that hitherto our errors alone have been assimilated by us, and **that all our consciousness refers to errors**!

Is **“and that our consciousness consists entirely of errors”** possible?

Reply in English, please.

Comment: In this context "awareness" may be a better choice. See https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5257/what-is-the-difference-between-bewu%c3%9ftsein-and-bewu%c3%9ftheit

Comment: Thank you for that comment. That is not the question, though.

Comment: No idea how to say that in English but with "awareness" it may not be "to refer to"... that's why I commented ;)

Comment: It is a stage in the development/evolution of 'the organic'. He apparently uses das Bewusstsein and die Bewusstheit interchangeably, given the opening of the section.

Comment: Why would you ask for answers in English?

Comment: Because I am translating it into English, and English is my native language.

Comment: Well, not that of many here, and if you tackle a translation of this kind then I would assume that your German is good enough to understand answers in German.

Comment: Not necessarily. I think in English, of course, and my questions are going to deal with the English translation. It's not really a matter of understanding German.

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding, *sich beziehen auf* is here used in the sense of *sich berufen auf,* which in turn I would translate as *to rely on, to be based on* or *to depend on* in this context. Thus some suggestion to translate that subclause would be (keeping your translation as far as possible, with roughly decreasing literalness):

> that all our consciousness depends on errors
>   that all our consciousness is based on errors
>   that all our consciousness relies on errors
>   that all our consciousness is built on errors
>   that all our consciousness originates from errors

Roughly comparable uses of *beziehen* can be found in sentences like:

> Er bezog sich auf Experimente, um seine These zu untermauern.
>   (He relied and referred to experiments to substantiate his thesis.)

---

> Is “and that our consciousness consists entirely of errors” possible?

It’s possible, but I think that *consist* is overly strong here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the revised version:

11
Das Bewusstsein.— Die Bewusstheit ist die letzte und späteste Entwickelung des Organischen und folglich auch das Unfertigste und Unkräftigste daran. Aus der Bewusstheit stammen unzählige Fehlgriffe, welche machen, dass ein Thier, ein Mensch zu Grunde geht, früher als es nöthig wäre, "über das Geschick," wie Homer sagt. Wäre nicht der erhaltende Verband der Instincte so überaus viel mächtiger, diente er nicht im Ganzen als Regulator: an ihrem verkehrten Urtheilen und Phantasiren mit offenen Augen, an ihrer Ungründlichkeit und Leichtgläubigkeit, kurz eben an ihrer Bewusstheit müsste die Menschheit zu Grunde gehen: oder vielmehr, ohne jenes gäbe es diese längst nicht mehr!

11.
Consciousness — Consciousness is the latest development of the organic, and is thus still quite imperfect, ill-formed, and weak compared to preceding developments. Consciousness leads to innumerable errors, which, ‘tempting fate’, as Homer says, cause an animal or a man to perish earlier than might otherwise be necessary. If the protective bond of the instincts were not very much more powerful, and if it did not generally serve as a regulator, mankind would necessarily have perished with open eyes from bad judgements and fantasies, from superficiality and credulity, in short, just from consciousness; or rather, without the instincts, mankind would have vanished long ago!

Bevor eine Function ausgebildet und reif ist, ist sie eine Gefahr des Organismus: gut, wenn sie so lange tüchtig tyrannisirt wird! So wird die Bewusstheit tüchtig tyrannisirt—und nicht am wenigsten von dem Stolze darauf! Man denkt, hier sei der Kern des Menschen; sein Bleibendes, Ewiges, Letztes, Ursprünglichstes! Man hält die Bewusstheit für eine feste gegebene Grösse! Leugnet ihr Wachsthum, ihre Intermittenzen! Nimmt sie als Einheit des Organismus!—Diese lächerliche Ueberschätzung und Verkennung des Bewusstseins hat die grosse Nützlichkeit zur Folge, dass damit eine allzuschnelle Ausbildung desselben verhindert worden ist. Weil die Menschen die Bewusstheit schon zu haben glaubten, haben sie sich wenig Mühe darum gegeben, sie zu erwerben—und auch jetzt noch steht es nicht anders! Es ist immer noch eine ganz neue und eben erst dem menschlichen Auge aufdämmernde, kaum noch deutlich erkennbare Aufgabe, das Wissen sich einzuverleiben und instinctiv zu machen,—eine Aufgabe, welche nur von Denen gesehen wird, die begriffen haben, dass bisher nur unsere Irrthümer uns einverleibt waren und dass alle unsere Bewusstheit sich auf Irrthümer bezieht!

Before a function is fully formed and mature, it is a danger to the organism,; thus it is well and good if it is thoroughly suppressed until then! So, consciousness is thoroughly suppressed — and not least by our pride in it! It is believed that herein lies the essence of man; that which is abiding, eternal, ultimate, and most original in him! Consciousness is regarded as being a fixed, given state, incapable of growth or advancing through intermediate stages! It is accepted as the ‘unity of the organism’! This ludicrous overestimation and misconception of consciousness has happily prevented it from maturing too rapidly. Because men believed that they already possessed consciousness, they scarcely bothered trying to acquire it, and this remains true today! The need to assimilate knowledge and make it instinctive is just now beginning to be recognized, and as of yet is not fully discernible — it is a need which is seen only by those who have grasped the fact that hitherto our errors alone have been assimilated by us, and that our consciousness rests entirely upon errors!